# Slack API returns {'ok': False, 'error': 'not_authed'} error

Tags: python, slack

I'm trying to upload image to slack with slack api. My connections settings looks fine but im getting not_authed error. I'm trying to request with https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload this method.

[image]

**Bot user have *files:write* permission;**
[image]

```
def sendtoslack(request):
    image = request.POST.get('imageData')
    imagestr = str(image)
    x = imagestr[22:]
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.decodebytes(bytes(x, "utf-8"))))
    user = request.user.username
    showtime = str(datetime.datetime.today())
    a = 'static/xx/ss-' + user + '-' + showtime[:19] + '.png'
    img.save(a)
    img = os.path.abspath(a)
    client = WebClient(token=os.environ.get("xoxb-XX-XX-XX"))
    channel_id = "XX"
    client.files_upload(
            channels=channel_id,
            initial_comment="1",
            file=img,
    )
    return render(request, 'xx.html')
```

Comment: Make sure perms are set and pass your key hard coded into `client = WebClient(token=os.environ.get("xoxb-XX-XX-XX")) ` instead of an environmental variable to ensure the key works fine.

Comment: you mean should send to key with variable in to client variable?

Comment: client = WebClient(token="xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx")